# How can I list all the repositories of a Github Organization by URL?

Tags: github-api

I would like to use the Github api to fetch all the repositories owned by a Github organization account.

For example, Let's say I have

https://github.com/apache

How do I use the github api to fetch all the sub repositories inside this URL?

Input: `https://github.com/apache`

Output: `['https://github.com/apache/phoenix','https://github.com/apache/accumulo-testing', ...]`

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their Api limits to 100 results per request(and has some other limits, such as 60 unauthenticated requests per hour). So depending on how programmatically you are doing this, you would want to make your requests as follows:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/apache/repos?page=1&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/orgs/apache/repos?page=2&per_page=100
etc...
```